# What is Cacheability constraint in REST API?

Tags: rest

"REST constraints state that Server responses also need to contain information about whether caching is allowed for the delivered resource."

The above article is from ibm website.

I saw many REST api videos but in none of them they set response header for cacheability does that mean they are not following rest constraint ?  How to implement this rest constraint in node js?

Answer (score 0):

The authoritative definition of the REST architectural style is [Fielding's 2000 dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4).

> In order to improve network efficiency, we add cache constraints

> The advantage of adding cache constraints is that they have the potential to partially or completely eliminate some interactions, improving efficiency, scalability, and user-perceived performance by reducing the average latency of a series of interactions.  The trade-off, however, is that a cache can decrease reliability if stale data within the cache differs significantly from the data that would have been obtained had the request been sent directly to the server.

---

HTTP Caching is currently defined by https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19  In particular, the fields (headers) that describe the caching semantics of responses are defined in [section 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19#section-5).

> For a cache to store and use a response, the associated method needs to explicitly allow caching -- [HTTP Semantics, 9.2.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.2.3)

HTTP Semantics itself defines the specifics of caching of responses when the request method is [GET](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.1), [HEAD](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.2), or [POST](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.3).